How to align <div> containers based on border position and midline?
I am trying to create a bracket for a sports tournament in HTML and CSS (using JS later to be able to interact with it).
So far my concept is to use  containers with only the top, bottom, and right-side borders to create this effect. I apologize for the crudeness, but something like this (the solid lines are solid borders and the dashed lines are borders that are not present). However, I am not able to find how to align the  containers with each other the way I want.
How do you align  containers by their borders and midlines? (align the top border of one div container in-line with the horizontal midline of another container)
So far I have asked lady Google a bunch, poked around Stack Overflow, and read MDN resources, but I cannot find anything that fits with my problem.
The next thing I am going to try is using a bunch of  containers to get the positions I want by stacking them to fit, but I feel like that is going to get messy quickly, so I figured I would see if there are any better solutions out there.
Any nudge in the right direction/similar post or online resource/advice/fix would be greatly appreciated :)

Could you make it clearer what your content structure is? e.g. how will you 'know' which column a name is to be in and how will you know how many columns you need? The structure looks like a grid, but we don't have the info to know how to set it up at present.

I have edited the post so hopefully that helps. The solid lines are solid borders and the dashed lines are borders that are not present. As you can see, I am trying to align the bottom and top of a div container with the midline of two others.

Sorry, I wasn’t clear - I wasn’t asking about what mat, or may not, be the CSS related solution, but how you will know how many rounds there will be, how the info on who is in each round will be available to you. What is the data structure?

Oh, I see, I will try to answer to the best of my ability, I am new to programming so please bear with me :) The number of rounds is determined by the user (which is why I was trying to make it easier to add on certain parts of the bracket), the info on who is in each round is from a database and selected through a dropdown menu, and I'm not sure what you mean by data structure, but I'm assuming that would be the tables in the database? Please let me know if I need to clarify further :)

I come up with something like this! Hope this helps. It will auto adjust depending on the items in columns. I also added placeholders where the team names probably will be


.team-name {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.path.root {
  border: solid calc(var(--border-width) / 2) black;
  height: 0;
}

.path {
  --border-width: 4px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid var(--border-width) black;
  border-left: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.path-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col>div {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <div class="path"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="path"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="path"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="path"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <div class="path">
        <div class="path-content">
          <div class="team-name">Team 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="path">
        <div class="path-content">
          <div class="team-name">Team 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <div class="path"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <div class="path root"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




wow, thank you so much :) that is super helpful :) However, my original question still is how to align  containers using their borders and midlines, or is that not a possibility? I am just trying to give myself a larger spot to put the Team Names for increased readability and compactness (like on my diagram I reduced space by putting the names in the boxes rather than on the lines meaning a the input is positioned differently), and better its componentization by making the addition of more brackets more simpler. I really appreciate your response though, it really really does help a lot :)

And also please let me know if there is any more information or clarification I need to give as well, or if I am not understanding you correctly :)

I am not really sure what you mean by "align by borders" because border is around div element. You can align div in another div by absolute position, padding or using flex. Of course, you can create lines with div with zero height or width with absolute positions, but that would be probably more complicated

Oh okay I see, I was thinking if there was a way to align  containers like images in Google Slides or Microsoft Powerpoint or another presentation software where you can drag and drop images to align with each others' characteristics - e.g. top border to bottom border, midline to bottom border, etc. But if this is not possible then I will use a solution similar to yours in stacking  containers (if you look at the updated diagram I made, the  containers are what hold the Team Names, and the  containers between them create the lines between each level.)

You could use CSS grid - the number of columns being the number of rounds + 1 and the number of rows being (number of rounds) * (number of rounds).
For a general solution I imagine you will want to code this [depending on where the data is and how it is presented this might be in Javascript or on some backend scripting].
This snippet demonstrates the idea with 4 rounds - so 16 players (or teams) to begin with.
The lines are drawn using linear-gradients.


<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .rounds {
    display: grid;
    --n: 5;
    grid-template-columns: var(--n);
    gap: 0;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .rounds>* {
    display: contents;
    font-size: calc(100vh / (1.5 * (var(--n) * var(--n))));
    /* for demo so it fits */
  }
  
  .rounds>*>* {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  }
  
  .rounds>*>*>span {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 0.5em));
  }
  
  .rounds>*>*:nth-child(odd) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px) 100%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 98%, black 98% 100%);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 50%;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 bottom;
  }
  
  .rounds>*>*:nth-child(even) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px) 100%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 98%, black 98% 100%);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 50%;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 top;
  }
  
  .rounds>*:last-child>*:last-child {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px) 100%);
  }
  
  .rounds>*:nth-child(1)>* {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  
  .rounds>*:nth-child(2)>* {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
  }
  
  .rounds>*:nth-child(3)>* {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: span 4;
  }
  
  .rounds>*:nth-child(4)>* {
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: span 8;
  }
  
  .rounds>*:nth-child(5)>* {
    grid-column: 5;
    grid-row: span 16;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="rounds">
    <div class="round">
      <div class="entry"><span>A</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>B</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>C</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>D</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>E</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>F</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>G</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>H</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>I</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>J</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>K</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>L</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>M</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>N</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>O</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>P</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
      <div class="entry"><span>A</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>C</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>E</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>G</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>I</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>K</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>M</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>O</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
      <div class="entry"><span>A</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>E</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>I</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>M</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
      <div class="entry"><span>A</span></div>
      <div class="entry"><span>I</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
      <div class="entry"><span>A</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>




Thank you for your help :) I never thought of this solution before using the linear-gradients is smart. This is probably the closest to what I was hoping to make, however my original question is still if there are other ways to align  containers to each other, rather than the container in which they are in? Like aligning the bottom edge of one  container with the bottom edge of another  container or the midline of one  container with the top of another?

If this is not possible then I will probably end up stacking  containers and using the linear gradients (because that was a really good idea.)

you can use postion top right left etc and margin also to align divs where u want

I am looking to align these  containers in reference to one another, not the page itself or from the container to the content it holds (unless I do not understand those attributes correctly) thank you for your response :) please let me know if I need to clarify further :)

from when you start coding?

I started coding recently, so please bear with me, I am still learning :)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
